# Number of bytes that trie takes up in memory - C

Tags: c

I am coding up a trie as a practice exercise for learning some fundamentals in C. My insert, delete, and search functions are seem to be working just fine. However, I am not so sure about my function that attempts to return the number of bytes that the Trie rooted at node takes up in memory.

```
unsigned int memory_trie_node(struct TrieNode *node)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < LETTER_COUNT; i++)
    {
        struct TrieNode *next = node->children[i];
        if (next != NULL)
        {
            return sizeof(next) + memory_trie_node(next);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are my struct definitions

```
struct TrieNode {
    struct TrieNode* children[LETTER_COUNT];
    int wordEnds; // 1 if string ends at this node, 0 else
};

struct Trie {
    struct TrieNode* root;
};
```

The way I am creating a new trie node seems to be working fine, as is the way I am dynamically allocating memory, but I can include the other functions if need be.

Is my memory_trie_node function correct? If not, what can I do to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't `sizeof(next)` be `sizeof(*next)`?

Comment: I think that the return is too early.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Ah, thanks - had not heard of that before!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a little change to your recursion approach: handle the current node at the start of function and only consider the child nodes in the loop:

```
unsigned int memory_trie_node(struct TrieNode* node)
{
    int i, memory;
    if (!node) return 0;

    memory = sizeof(struct TrieNode); // self size
    for(i = 0; i < LETTER_COUNT; i++)
    {
        memory += memory_trie_node(node->children[i]);
    }
    return memory;
}
```

Comment: Intuitively, this makes a lot of sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: @Kyle I see you haven't yet accepted any answer to your questions. When your question is answered, you should accept an answer. Otherwise it would be good to clarify your questions so answers can be edited with more details. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(i = 0; i < LETTER_COUNT; i++) {
      struct TrieNode* next = node->children[i];
      if (next != NULL) {
          return sizeof(next) + memory_trie_node(next);
      }
  }
```

You are just calculating the size of the first `non null` child and recursing on that `non null` child but what about the other children.You don't let the loop complete.

You also have to take into account the current node.After all even if all children of a node are `null`, the size should not be `zero`

```
 unsigned int totalMemory=0;
 if(node == NULL)
     return 0;
 for(i = 0; i < LETTER_COUNT; i++) {
      struct TrieNode* next = node->children[i];
      if (next != NULL) {
          totalMemory+= memory_trie_node(next));
      }
  } 
  return totalMemory + sizeof(struct TrieNode);
```

EDIT: Added the case to handle the case where `node=null`.The size should be zero in that case

Comment: Full question contains the following: *"If not, what can I do to fix it?"*. I'll happily revisit when the stub turned into an answer

Comment: Might be a silly question, but by defining totalmemory = 0 prior to the for loop, will totalmemory still return the total memory for all nodes?

Comment: @Kyle between the `return` and `totalMemory=0`, the for loop will take care of the child nodes.